# ffdshow filter cannot be selected in Media Player Classic-HC

Tags: codec, media-player-classic, ffdshow

I installed ffdshow on my Windows 8.1 x64, as you can see:

[image]

My MPC-HC can't see it as an external filter:

[image]

Where should I look for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the **x64**. I had to install ffdshow x64 to appear in the external filter list.